# How to link an arm .o file into an Xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode, linker, arm

I have a gnu built object file I need to include in an Xcode iPhone project. The .o file format is arm, via 'otool -h':

```
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
 0xfeedface      12          0  0x00          1     3       1316 0x00002000
```

But Xcode rejects it, complaining that "file is not of required architecture". It accepts arm6 files (e.g. cpusubtype=6) but I am struggling to modify the GNU makefile to produce arm6 libraries.

Is there an Xcode project setting that allows linking in arm object files?

Environment:
Xcode: 3.1.4
iPhone SDK: 2.2.1
Arch: Standard (armv6)

Comment: Can you give some more details?  How did you build this object file?  Why not just build it with the rest of your app?

Comment: It's a long story, but the crux is: Xcode seems to support linking to arm6 object files, but not arm object files. Is this correct or am I missing a project setting?